# i have a script to log out disconnected users it create output file. but it alway get replace with new

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a script to log out disconnected users and it creates an output file, but it always get replaced with a new version. I want my script to create a new file always with date.

```
@echo off
query user > D:\logoff.txt
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=,: " %%a in ('query user ^| find /i "disc"')  
do logoff %%b
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the output requirements are.

```
query user > D:\logoff.txt
```

not a standard winbatch command, but `>` will send output to a new file, deleting the old.

To **append** to the file, use `>>` in place of `>`

To output the date to its own line, use

```
echo %date% >> D:\logoff.txt
```

To output the date and time to its own line, use

```
echo %date% %time% >> D:\logoff.txt
```

and `%username%` should normally contain the name of the current user, which may save you from having to run `query user`

Comment: ... and `echo %username% >> %date:/=-%.txt` create a file with the date in the name, and store the current user there.

Comment: i want out put is users who are login in server.

Comment: and don't want to append want new output file.